# Capturing Response Size - HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have an application where the users are accessing a servlet file which will read a .pdf file conditionally and send the .pdf file as response to the users request. The servlet code does not sets the content length on the response header.

- In the above scenario I want to capture the Response Size of the each user request without making any changes in the servlet code.
- At the same time I do not want to use the HttpServletResponseWrapper for some other reasons.

Please suggest me on the possible ways to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can add code then you could create a filter for this.  Otherwise you'll need a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Every container supports **Web Access Logging**. Look for that and enable it. It will log the response content length along with other request and response parameters.